# How do I add a new line to a string in python

Tags: python, string, list, printing

I have this code

```
def fullview():    
    rows = 3
    elems_in_row = 4
    List = ['-'] * rows
    for i in range(rows):
        List[i] = ['-'] * elems_in_row   
    for i in List:
        elements = ''.join(i)
        fullview = str(rows)+ ':' + elements
        rows -= 1
   return fullview
```

When i add a line to fullview it removes the previous line added to it.
My desired result is:

```
fullview = """
3:----
2:----
1:----
"""
```

Im not sure how to add the new line correctly to the string since += dont work.

Comment: BTW, it's not a good idea to use the name of a function for a variable inside the function. It won't hurt anything in your code, but it would if your function were recursive. But the main reason not to do it is that it makes the code confusing to read.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done a single construction, instead of multiple steps:

```
result = '\n'.join(['{}:{}'.format(i, '-' * elements_in_row)
                    for i in range(1, rows + 1)][::-1])
```

One reason the original code did not work is that the line updating `fullview` did not take into account the previous state:

```
fullview = str(rows)+ ':' + elements
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use '\n'

```
def fullview():
    rows = 3
    elems_in_row = 4
    fullview_str = ''
    for i in range(rows, 0, -1):
        fullview_str += "{}:{}\n".format(i, '-' * elems_in_row)
    return fullview_str
```

Example output:

```
3:----
2:----
1:----
```